# how can dotfile executeable issue on codespace?

Tags: github, dotfiles, codespaces, github-codespaces

Good day!

when I enable `Automatically install dotfiles` in the GitHub codespace setting and follow create codespace, my dotfiles are not found, and the install script is not run!

[my dotfile repo](https://github.com/njfamirm/dotfiles)

When I see the log, codespace says install.sh script not executable!

how can fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you must make this file executable with git...

```
git rm --cached install.sh
git add install.sh --chmod=+x
```

and next, commit and push to the repo!